# community license update lead rest

Tags: community, rest-api

We have a rest api that is available to our partners to access Leads/Opportunities.  Due to limited Salesforce licenses it was recommended to use Community License for this service; this license has access to the connected app.

This has worked until recently we need to provide ability to update Leads/Opportunities. Since Community License can't update others Leads/Opportunities, is there ways around this?  I know I can open "Sharing" but don't want to do that for all Communities Profiles.

Comment: What sort of updates do your users need to be able to make?

Comment: At this point its for API (partner access via Community License) and for now the API needs to update Lead or Opportunity custom fields

Comment: What kind of Community License?  Partner Community?  They should be able to edit Leads.  Can you give an example of a specific operation a user is trying to perform, and what isn't working with it?  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: We have "Customer Community Login"; which only allow read of Lead/Opportunity (unless you change "Sharing Settings" which we don't want to do).  We don't have Partner license; these do let you update Leads/Opportunities but we don't want to have to purchase one of these if there's another way to allow using the API to update Lead/Opportunity